# Passing parameters to jQuery from Django View and using callback functions based on if else condition

Tags: django, jquery, django-forms, django-views

I have a popup login form in my base.html

```
<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
    <a href="#" class="close"><img src="http://localhost:8000/static/media/close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>
      <form method="post" class="signin" action="{% url login_view %}" id="LoginForm">
          <div id="ajaxwrapper">
            <fieldset class="textbox">
            <label class="username">
            <span>Username</span>
            <input id="username" name="username" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Username">
            </label>
            <label class="password">
            <span>Password</span>
            <input id="password" name="password" value="" type="password" placeholder="Password">
            </label>
            <p id="sendwrapper"></p>
            <p><button id="submitbutton" type="submit">Sign in</button></p>
            <p>
            <a class="forgot" href="/accounts/password/reset/">Forgot your password?</a>
            </p>       
            </fieldset>
          </div>
      </form>
```

On submit this form calls the below function in Django view:

```
def login_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print "%s" % repr(request.POST) 
        print "%s" % repr(request.GET) 
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        user = authenticate(username=cd['username'], password=cd['password'])
        print user
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
               login(request, user)
               # success
               response_dict = 'success' 
               return render_to_response("tr/login.html", { 'username' : user , 'response_dict' : response_dict })
            else:
               # disabled account
               response_dict = 'The account is disabled'
               return render_to_response("tr/login.html", { 'response_dict' : response_dict })
        else:
           # invalid login
           response_dict = 'Username or Password is not correct'
           return render_to_response("tr/login.html", { 'response_dict' : response_dict })
    else:
        print "%s" % repr(form.errors)
```

Now I want to keep up the popup login box for every unsucessfull attempt and close it on sucessfull attempt. For this I am trying the below jQuery code. But I do not know how to handle it.

```
jQuery(function() {
  var form = jQuery("#LoginForm");
  form.submit(function(e) {
      var a = 1;
      jQuery("#submitbutton").attr('disabled', true)
      jQuery("#sendwrapper").prepend('<span>Sending message, please wait... </span>')
      if(a==1){jQuery("#ajaxwrapper").load(
          form.attr('action') + ' #ajaxwrapper',
          form.serializeArray(),
          function(responseText, responseStatus) {
              jQuery("#sendwrapper").html('<span> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA </span>')    
              jQuery("#sendbutton").attr('disabled', false)
          }
      )}
      else{jQuery("#ajaxwrapper").load(
          form.attr('action') + ' #ajaxwrapper',
          form.serializeArray(),
          function(responseText, responseStatus) {
              jQuery("#sendwrapper").html('<span> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA </span>')    
              jQuery("#sendbutton").attr('disabled', false)
          }
      )};
      e.preventDefault(); 
  });
 });
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

In your login_view, return "success" to the template. If login was successful, success=True else success=False.

In your template, you can check if success == True, close the popup.

Btw, your variables are a little confusing. I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
response_dict['message'] = 'Login successful.' 
response_dict['success'] = True
response_dict['user'] = user
return render_to_response("tr/login.html", response_dict)
```

You also do not need to pass the user to template if you do this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates